# How to hide php actions from history?

Tags: php, http-headers

Is it possible to tell the browser that he should not remember the action scripts page?

So when you delete a headline for example. The get action will be ?d=ID where ID is the id of the headline. After removing the headline go to the page without the get variable in the url (the header part).

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['d']) && preg_match('{^[0-9]{1,3}$}',$_GET['d'])){
    $hid = $_GET['d'];
    $deletesql = "DELETE FROM headlines WHERE hid = $hid";
    mysql_query($deletesql);
    header('Location: panel.php');} ?>
```

But now you browser history shows the link panel.php?d=23
Can prevent the browser from remembering the page? Maybe a 303 header?

Comment: The fundamental problem here is that you are using GET for something you should be using POST for. GET is designed to be safe and repeatable. POST is designed for *doing* things. You're looking for a work around to a side effect of you using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: well how do you send POST with link? Or an image?

Comment: You don't use a link. You use a form. You can then style the submit button however you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the ID hidden in the form and then get it in the form action part using $_POST and then do the delete action and redirect once delete is successful to avoid user from re posting the form.

Answer (score 4):

You should use POST instead of GET for this. That way the browser will prompt the user if he wants to send the information again. (typically the id argument)

Comment: well how do you send POST with link? Or an image?